# In python, trying to combine elements from a list of lists into a new list of combined-element lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I am a python newbie.

I have a list of lists:

```
test=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
```

I want to combine the elements of each list so that I get as a result:

```
result = [[1,4,7,10],[2,5,8,11],[3,6,9,12]]
```

I am looking for a solution that will work for n elements and where the answer is a list of lists (a list of tuples will not work for me).  Ideally, I would like test to have n elements instead of a definite number.

I wish that the following would work:

```
result = map(zip,test)
```

But it does not.

Is there a straight forward way to do this?

Comment: it looks as though you are wanting to do vector functions with lists?  mapping and zipping are limited in scope to simpler list functions.  If you want more complex functions consider using sets.

Comment: @Prune, I don't think so.  That one is referring to a list of tuples as an answer.  I am specifically looking for a list of lists as an answer.

Comment: The difference is a trivial type-cast operation.  I feel that the significant part of this question is the **zip(*test)** insight.  I chose the above question as the one that illustrates this insight most readily.

Comment: I'm a newbie.  If I had found the other question, it wasn't obvious to me that it would have answered my question.  Please keep in mind that my question will be trivial to me in about 1 month.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result = map(list, zip(*test))
```

Comment: Thanks.  This gives me the elements as a list.

Answer (score 4):

You are not looking for [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).

You are looking for [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) with unpacking, this function does exactly what you want:

```
result = zip(*test)
# [(1, 4, 7, 10), (2, 5, 8, 11), (3, 6, 9, 12)]
```

If you really need a list of lists, there you can use `map()`:

```
result = map(list, zip(*test))
# [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
```

Note that if you are using Python 3, `zip()` and `map()` no longer return a `list`, so you may need to wrap the whole expression with a `list()` cast.

Comment: Thanks!  I had forgotten the asterisk.  :-)